# I am having csv file can I know how to replace spaces in column heading with underscore in linux

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

My actual input will be like this, in column heading I need linux command to replace spaces with underscores

**INPUT:**

```
patient name age number of days
 santhosh    24      20
 saravanan    23     25
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
 patient_name age number_of_days
   santhosh    24      20
   saravanan   23      25
```

Comment: Kindly do mention what you have tried to solve your own problem in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Actually, my table consists of 20 columns along with 1500 data. My problem here is those column names have space in between them. I need to replace those spaces with an underscore.

Comment: Show your own efforts first. Also what's the file separated with?  How do we avoid the underscore been added like this `name_age`?

Comment: Are you sure your input is CSV? There's no commas in the sample you posted...

Comment: using awk, look to use printf and format (like "%9s")  with field ( like $9).  Put some try, we will help based on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so assuming your CSV is tab delimited, I'd suggest what you want is `split`.

```
while ( <> ) {
   print join "\t", map { s/\s+/_/gr } split /\t/; 
}
```

This will split on tabs, transform each 'entry' by replacing one or more spaces with underscores, and print the resultant line.

Comment: my csv file is comma separater

Comment: Your example is not though. Your sample data in your question is tab separated. Either way though - you can swap the `\t` for `,` and it'll work much the same.

Comment: this is another way.  head -1 npidata.csv | perl -pe "s/ /_/g" >npidata1.csv

Comment: Well, you could just do `sed -i 's/ /_/g' npidata.csv'`. But `sed` in that scenario is blind to the delimiters, and isn't handling it as csv but rather plain text.